# DAX forecasting deadline breach

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I will need your help with the problem I am facing regarding DAX:

We have a table that shows the when a new batch of cases will be generated and how many cases are expected:

```
idx  batch_date   new_cases
1    5/1/2020     1504  
2    5/3/2020     2005
3    5/13/2020    921
4    5/26/2020    770
```

we also know that on average, every day 95 cases will be worked and closed, and the assumption is that newer batch will not be worked until the previous one is completed; we also have calculations showing when batch reaches aging of 10 and 15.

```
idx  batch_date   new_cases  production  days  batch_start  batch end  day_10     day_15
1    5/1/2020     1504       95          16    5/1/2020     5/17/2020  5/11/2020  5/16/2020
2    5/3/2020     2005       95          22    5/18/2020    6/9/2020   5/13/2020  5/18/2020
3    5/13/2020    921        95          10    6/10/2020    6/20/2020  5/23/2020  5/28/2020
4    5/26/2020    770        95          9     6/21/2020    6/30/2020  6/5/2020   6/10/2020
```

in regular Excel I would use these formulas:

```
days: =ROUNDUP([@[new_cases]]/[@production]],0)
batch_start: =if(*batch_end previous row* >=[@[batch_date]], *batch_end previous row*+1,[@[batch_date]]) 
batch_end: =[@[batch_start]]+[@[days]]
day_10: = [@[batch_date]]+10
day_15: = [@[batch_date]]+15
```

first problem:
when I try to write a DAX calculated column for *batch_start*,

```
batch_start:= IF(LOOKUPVALUE(
                     forecast[batch_end], forecast[idx], forecast[idx] -1) >= forecast[batch_date],
                     forecast[batch_end], forecast[idx], forecast[idx] -1) +1,
                     forecast[batch_date])
```

I obviously get a circular dependency error. Any idea how to resolve that?

The other problem is that the ultimate goal of this exercise is to count how many cases we have in each aging bucket (<=10, 11-15, >15) on every day. I.e., on 5/2 I have 1409 open cases from 5/1 batch (1504 - 95 already processed), all in <=10 bucket; on 5/28 I have 770 in <=10 bucket, 921 in 11-15 bucket and 1055 in >15 bucket etc. Any idea how to write a measure that would show that? I put on DropBox a xlsx file where I manually counted the expected outcome (https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgfgdtcxqilxfnm/forecast.xlsx?dl=0).
The reason I need this in DAX is that previous steps of the entire project are done using PowerQuery, PowerPivot and DAX, and this will be the very last puzzle of the project.

```
            batch:                                     expected outcome:
            5/1   5/3   5/13  5/26   all open cases    <=10  11-15  >15
2020-05-01  1504                     1504              1504  0      0
2020-05-02  1409                     1409              1409  0      0
2020-05-03  1314  2005               3319              3319  0      0
2020-05-04  1219  2005               3224              3224  0      0
2020-05-05  1124  2005               3129              3129  0      0
2020-05-06  1029  2005               3034              3034  0      0
2020-05-07  934   2005               2939              2939  0      0
2020-05-08  839   2005               2844              2844  0      0
2020-05-09  744   2005               2749              2749  0      0
2020-05-10  649   2005               2654              2654  0      0
2020-05-11  554   2005               2559              2559  0      0
2020-05-12  459   2005               2464              2005  459    0
2020-05-13  364   2005  921          3290              2926  364    0
2020-05-14  269   2005  921          3195              921   2274   0
2020-05-15  174   2005  921          3100              921   2179   0
2020-05-16  79    2005  921          3005              921   2084   0
2020-05-17  0     2005  921          2926              921   2005   0
2020-05-18        2005  921          2926              921   2005   0
2020-05-19        1910  921          2831              921   0      1910
2020-05-20        1815  921          2736              921   0      1815
2020-05-21        1720  921          2641              921   0      1720
2020-05-22        1625  921          2546              921   0      1625
2020-05-23        1530  921          2451              921   0      1530
2020-05-24        1435  921          2356              0     921    1435
2020-05-25        1340  921          2261              0     921    1340
2020-05-26        1245  921   770    2936              770   921    1245
2020-05-27        1150  921   770    2841              770   921    1150
2020-05-28        1055  921   770    2746              770   921    1055
2020-05-29        960   921   770    2651              770   0      1881
2020-05-30        865   921   770    2556              770   0      1786
2020-05-31        770   921   770    2461              770   0      1691
2020-06-01        675   921   770    2366              770   0      1596
2020-06-02        580   921   770    2271              770   0      1501
2020-06-03        485   921   770    2176              770   0      1406
2020-06-04        390   921   770    2081              770   0      1311
2020-06-05        295   921   770    1986              770   0      1216
2020-06-06        200   921   770    1891              0     770    1121
2020-06-07        105   921   770    1796              0     770    1026
2020-06-08        10    921   770    1701              0     770    931
2020-06-09        0     921   770    1691              0     770    921
2020-06-10              921   770    1691              0     770    921
2020-06-11              826   770    1596              0     0      1596
2020-06-12              731   770    1501              0     0      1501
2020-06-13              636   770    1406              0     0      1406
2020-06-14              541   770    1311              0     0      1311
2020-06-15              446   770    1216              0     0      1216
2020-06-16              351   770    1121              0     0      1121
2020-06-17              256   770    1026              0     0      1026
2020-06-18              161   770    931               0     0      931
2020-06-19              66    770    836               0     0      836
2020-06-20              0     770    770               0     0      770
2020-06-21                    770    770               0     0      770
2020-06-22                    675    675               0     0      675
2020-06-23                    580    580               0     0      580
2020-06-24                    485    485               0     0      485
2020-06-25                    390    390               0     0      390
2020-06-26                    295    295               0     0      295
2020-06-27                    200    200               0     0      200
2020-06-28                    105    105               0     0      105
2020-06-29                    10     10                0     0      10
2020-06-30                    0      0                 0     0      0
2020-07-01                    0      0                 0     0      0
```

Again, I would appreciate your help.

Best regards, Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have no gaps in production, you can calculate `batch_start` by taking the first `batch_generation_date` and rolling forward the cumulative number production days.

```
batch_start =
VAR FirstBatchDate = MIN ( forecast[batch_generation_date] )
VAR CurrBatchDate = forecast[batch_generation_date]
VAR CumulativeDays =
    SUMX (
        FILTER ( forecast, forecast[batch_generation_date] < CurrBatchDate ),
        forecast[days] + 1
    )
RETURN
    FirstBatchDate + CumulativeDays
```